# WP redirection plugin, redirect urls with multiple query strings

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I am using Redirection plugin to create 301 for a site I updated.
I created redirects from urls with multiple query vars like:

```
  /news/news.asp?p=hear-this&cat=news
```

to new urls like

```
 /news/hear-this
```

Theese redirect gives 404.

The problem are multiple query vars

If you go to url /news/news.asp?p=hear-this the redirect works, if you go the url with the seconnd or multiple query vars it does not.

How to have the redirects work no matter how many query vars are in the url treating it as a whole 'string'?

Comment: I have just realized that the problem happens only when trying to redirect url with s= var in query string.
The s= get var is used by wordpress search.... changing that may solve the issue... how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was given by the query var `&s=` in the url to redirect. Wordpress uses the variable for its core search.

I had to make a rule in .htaccess to remove that query var from the url:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&?&s=[^&]+&?(.*)$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1?%1%2 [R=301,L]
```

Then reformat all my redirects removing the &s= from the url to redirect.

Trick done. Now all redirects work fine.